# How make upload app to itunes connect in xcode 4.2.1?

Tags: ipad, ios5, xcode4.2, distribution, app-store-connect

Can anyone give a guide from the start how to upload a iOS 5 Xcode 4.2.1 app to iTunes Connect?

And what is my SKU Number (Where can i find it?) .

Currently it reports: Status: Waiting For Upload
And i'm waiting for a iOS Paid Apps Contract.
But i can't workout how to upload a iPad iOS5 app on Xcode 4.2.1!
And i can't find distribution settings in my app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SKU # you make up.  It will be used in your sales and financial reports to identify the product.

In XCode, perform an Archive build.  Be sure the Archive action is configured to use your Release/Distribution build configuration (and that is set the way you want).  From the XCode organizer you can view your archived builds.  Select the one you want to submit and click "Validate".  Select your distribution code signing certificate.  If it doesn't validate, correct any issues.

Then select "Submit".  The validation process will repeat and your app will be uploaded.

Comment: iPhone/iPod Touch: Info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimensions, no icon found.  Your MinimumOSVersion is below 3.2, so you must define CFBundleIconFile or provide a default Icon.png that is 57x57. (-19013) This a warning i just got while Archieving!

Comment: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
I also get this warning!

Comment: As I said, you'll need to correct those issues before you can successfully submit.  If you don't know how to fix these I suggest you research the solutions and post separate questions if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I have corrected the warnings but Xcode 4.2.1 crashes while Validating... !